# parsing data with regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have string: text and something and something like `f213 @@ -1,9 +1,11 @@` etc etc and litle more etc etc

i woul dlike to get now `@@ -1,9 +1,11 @@.` Numbers are not fixed and can be changed...

My regex which not working:

> (@@ -)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)( +)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)( @@)

Can someone see error in my regex?

Comment: ( +) should be ( \+) It's a really weird regexp, though.

Comment: They don't make the regex wrong, but you also don't need any of your round brackets, unless you want to capture e.g. the numbers themselves. `@@ -[0-9]+,[0-9]+ \+[0-9]+,[0-9]+ @@`

Comment: How about an actual snipet of data and not saying etc, etc,etc. Provide all different combinations. -1

Comment: @OmegaMan you mean you can't tell from the regex the OP provided what's being asked? Downvote's a bit harsh...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape your plus:

```
(@@ -)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)( \+)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)( @@)
```

By the way, this is the best tool ever: http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx when trying to see what a regex is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an other solution :

```
Regex.IsMatch(yourString, @"@@\s(.+?)\s(.+?)\s@@", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

With your exemple, the group 1 will be "-1,9" and the group 2 "+1,11".

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `String.Split()`?

```
string input = "f213 @@ -1,9 +1,11 @@";
string[] fields = input.Split(new[] { "@@" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string result = "@@" + fields[1] + "@@";
```